# Configure Spring Cloud Gateway Response Timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Application with multiple services, eureka client and Spring cloud gateway to interact with services, the problem is from gateway client I am able to send request to the service in my service application's log I can see its arriving there but I am not able to get the response in my gateway application, my service is taking aroung 2-2.5 seconds to complete the request.

My Gateway Server Config:-

```
return route -> route.path("/" + serviceName + "/**")
                .filters(
                        filter -> filter.rewritePath("/" + serviceName + "", "/")
                                .circuitBreaker(circuit -> circuit.setName(DEFAULT_CIRCUIT_BREAKER)
                                        .setFallbackUri("forward:/service/" + fallbackUrl)))
                .uri("lb://" + serviceName + "");
```

here is my circuit breaker config:-

```
@Bean
    public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> circuitBreaker() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).build())
                .circuitBreakerConfig(io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults()).build());
    }
```

I also tried configuring per route response and timeout like below:-

```
return route -> route.path("/" + serviceName + "/**")
                .filters(
                        filter -> filter.rewritePath("/" + serviceName + "", "/")
                                .circuitBreaker(circuit -> circuit.setName(DEFAULT_CIRCUIT_BREAKER)
                                        .setFallbackUri("forward:/service/" + fallbackUrl)))
                .metadata(RouteMetadataUtils.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR, 5000) 
                .uri("lb://" + serviceName + "");
```

here is my application.yml file:-

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 10000
        response-timeout: 10s
```

what I am doing wrong